# Google Analytics New User Discrepancy (Acquisitions vs Audience)

Tags: google-analytics

We just created a new site and have added GA to the site. We are looking at New Users each day. When looking at the Acquisition Overview GA shows 167 new users for a period. When looking at Audience Overview GA shows 186 new users for the same period. Can anyone please explain the difference or maybe let me know some possible reasons for this. If you need more of an explanation please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The Audience overview report do not show New users. Where are you finding this metric in this report?

[image: Audience overview]

The acquisition overview shows New users during your time period, but this metric is not the same as the one showed in the audience overview report.

[image: Acquisition overview]

The audience overview report shows unique cookies, or users, while the acquisition report shows the amount of new users seen during the time period.